# What is this xPath trying to capture?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have come across this bit of jQuery and I am failing to understand what the xPath (?) means in this context:

```
var all_line_height = $(this).find("*[style*='line-height']");
```

I haven't seen this before, is it looking for an element that contains line-height in its style attribute?

I did a small test and it doesn't pick up on it.

Comment: The first asterisk is not necessary, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not XPath. It's a selector, which selects any element whose style attribute contains `line-height` from the currently selected element (`this`).

```
$(this)                     // selects the current element
       .find(...)           // Select all elements which match the selector:
   *[style*='line-height']  // Any element (*),
                            // whose style attribute ([style])
                            // contains "line-height"  (*='line-height')
```

It could be implemented as follows:

```
 // HTML:
// <div id="test">
//    <a style="line-height:10px;color:red;">...

$("#test").click(function(){
    // this points to <div id="test">
    var all_line_height = $(this).find("*[style*='line-height']");
    alert(all_line_height.length);    //Alerts 1
})
```